# Get the size of document before insert query in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, memory, mongoose

I have a situation where I have to get data from a stream and create a document in mongodb each time I get data from a stream. 
I can get the number of documents beforehand. 
I want to know how to determine the size of the documents on disk if and when the stream completes.
But I would like to know this before I start my process.
Is there a way to do this in mongodb.

I found `Object.bsonsize();` but it can only find the size after a query complete.

As of right now I am taking the product of the number of objects(data) from the stream and size of each object which I assume to be uniform throughout the stream.

Comment: Before insert query in mongodb you can query to get total count.
`db.collection.find().count()`

Comment: I want the size of the object I am inserting ...if and when it is inserted not the count of documents already in the db..

Comment: size of the object  can calculate using `var size = Object.keys(myObj).length;`

Comment: @AshwanthMadhav I don't think u understand the question...

Comment: MongoDB has no "query" method to determine a BSON size. There is **only** the utility method mentioned, and you either must run that on a returned object or within a `mapReduce()`.